# Separate two brothers from one element back into two fraternal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('ul.siblings').not(':first').remove().children('li').appendTo('ul:first');
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Hello, there is such an html structure, for example two **div's** in each of two `ul`, at a resolution of <681 px, **two** `ul` in the first `div` merge **into one** `ul` but the second `div` should not touch this, it must be in a passive state, and vice versa.

At a resolution> 680, in the **active div** one `ul` again got to the starting position by **two** `ul`, without losing the children. It is necessary to solve the task _ without the use of additional classes for elements.

Thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

**Are you referring to this perhaps?**

- Just the ul siblings of the first list div are joined together while the second one is seperated as it is.
  Using `.eq(0)` we are targetting the **first ul with the class siblings** and prepending the li to the first ul.

```js
$('ul.siblings').eq(0).remove().children('li').prependTo('ul:first');
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: blue;
}

.siblings {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>1
      <a>1</a>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li>2
      <a>2</a>
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='siblings'>
    <li>3
      <a>3</a>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <a>4</a>
      <div>4</div>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: I need a function that does **this with a resize less than 681**, and for a resize greater than 680, I need to return **one ul** from one div, into **two separate ul**